# No Compilation Error But Uncaught TypeError:Copy Text is null using copy.select()

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native

I Am Using React Development To Create An App Which Lets You Access Anonymous Mail
This Is Just A Showcase App To Get Starting In React

Basically My Script Is What Doing Is Generating A String Of email And Lets You CopyIt

function genrateStrings is creating a random string of email
and CopyIt Lets you Copy It
Here My Logic.js looks Like

```
const characters ='ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
export function generateString(length) 
{
    let result = ' ';
    let addr = "@example.com";
    const charactersLength = characters.length;
    for ( let i = 0; i < length; i++ ) 
    {
        result += characters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * charactersLength));
    }
    result=result+addr;

    return result;
}

export function CopyIt() 
{
  
    var copyText = document.getElementById("evar");
    copyText.select();
    copyText.setSelectionRange(0, 99999); 
    document.execCommand("copy");
    alert("Copied the text: " + copyText.value);
}
```

In My App.js I Am Using A Button To Call CopyIt() Function To Copy The Value Of Input Field Which Is Genrated Through genrateString Function

Here Is What My App,js looks Like

```
import './App.css';
import {generateString,CopyIt} from './logic.js';



var mail=generateString(9)


function App() {
  return (
   <> 
   <pre>
   <h1>This is Temporailry mail site </h1>
   <p>It helps you Access your Anynomyous mail without logins Required </p>
   </pre>
   <nav className="navbar navbar-light bg-light">
      <form className="container-fluid">
        <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon1">@</span>
        <input type="text" id="evar" class="form-control" value={mail} aria-label="Username" aria-describedby="basic-addon1"></input>
        <button onClick={CopyIt()}>Copy text</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </nav>

   </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Now When  I Am Trying To Run This App It Has No Compilation Error In Terminal
But On The Page Itself As A Type Error
Here Are Photos Attached
[TypeError](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3VL0K.png)
[Terminal succefully Compiled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N4sWN.png)

Comment: Does it directly run into the error or on click?

Comment: @Lynx242 Directly When The Page Load Itself No Error On Compilation Terminal But When I Switch To Webpage It Show Type Error Actually It Working Correctly At First Bunch Of Times And After i Remove One Line Which Is Importing Logo Unnecessary Which Comes With  But No Usage So I remove It And It StartGiving Me Error I Undo things But None Of Them Is Actually Working For Me

Comment: The Unnecessary Line Was import logo from './logo.svg'  which has nothing to do with logic

Comment: Okay, got it. I posted an answer. 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

REACT is calling `CopyIt()` directly when rendering. You have to cope with the fact that the input-element does not exist yet at this moment in time.

You can solve this race condition with an if-check.

```
export function CopyIt() 
{ 
    var copyText = document.getElementById("evar");

    if (copyText) {
        copyText.select();
        copyText.setSelectionRange(0, 99999); 
        document.execCommand("copy");
        alert("Copied the text: " + copyText.value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thnx It Actually Worked @Lynx242